# How to print contents of a for loop into a txt file? Python

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, txt

So I am trying to find out how many students there are, then ask that amount of students for their ID and print all the student IDs into a txt file followed by a dotted line(so they can sign the document)

This is my code so far:

```
i = 0
no_students = int(input("How many students are registering?"))
for student in range(i, no_students):
    if no_students > i:
        s_id = input("Enter your student ID: ")
        i += 1

with open("reg_form.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(str(f"Student ID: {s_id} ....................... \n"))
```

My issue is that only the last student input is transferred to the file. Also I don't know whether I should have the file be a or w. Any insight on that would be helpful.

I think I have to somehow loop the f.write in but not sure how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the last student is being recorded because you are calling the write method at the end of your code, outside of the for loop.

```
i = 0
no_students = int(input("How many students are registering?"))
for student in range(i, no_students):
    if no_students > i:
        s_id = input("Enter your student ID: ")
        i += 1

    with open("reg_form.txt", "a") as f:
        f.write(str(f"Student ID: {s_id} ....................... \n"))
```

And about the `"a"` or `"w"`, the `"a"` mode is going to append the new line to your file. And the `"w"` is going to overwrite it. [Python's input and output documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html)